# Spring Security SSO deployed on Cloud Foundry

Tags: spring-security, cloud-foundry

Looking for the spring security with SSO deployed on cloud foundry configuration or an example.

I have tried Spring security using CAS and Open Id works fine in local but deployment on cloud foundry fails.

Can somebody please help on what cloud foundry supports for the SSO & if possible provide me with an example ?

Thanks

Comment: Provide the logs from your application: vmc logs <app-name>

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Foundry has a open source project that is focus on SSO which takes care of user accounts and authentication.

Here you can find the source code along with documentation:

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa

Here is the section for the sample apps which you can use with UAA.
You can easily checkout the code and have it running on your localhost tomcat (servlet container) and try out the Single Sign On.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/tree/master/samples

The technology is using OAuth 2 implementation in Spring

Here is a nice presentation from Dr. Syer who is now part of Cloud Foundry as he demos his early works on UAA. Its of course become much complete and you can fully use it to your needs.

http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Identity-Management-with-Spring-Security?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter&goback=%2Egde_41311_member_96261662

Answer (score 1):

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/sample-apps.html
This one should cover all the sso samples in spring security. If you have trouble on deployment on cloud foundry, you can paste the detailed err log here so we can have a look.

Thanks,
William

Comment: Thanks William for the reply..I tried to change my security.xml as below

Answer (score 0):

CAS requires some Tomcat configuration. Did you update CF tomcat configuration in order to support CAS and HTTPS?
Provide also your Spring SSO configuration in order to investigate further.